# Investigating rational roots using the Hasse-Minkowski theorem.

Tags: quadratic-forms

I know of an example, found in this paper [here](http://www.math.union.edu/%7Ehatleyj/Capstone.pdf), where a polynomial is taken and, by using the Hasse-Minkowski theorem and investigating the behaviour over some primes, to conclude that it has a non-trivial root over $\Bbb Q$.

I am looking for more examples of this type to try and consolidate my understanding. Can we just take the polynomial and replace the coefficients with others and end up coming to a similar conclusion? For example, can we take say $f(x,y,z)=3x^2+11y^2-17z^2$ or are there specific conditions on the coefficients that will allow the conclusion of a non-trivial root over $\Bbb Q$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Hasse-Minkowski theorem works for quadratic forms like your $f$, but not for forms of higher degree. Does your $f=0$ have solutions in each $\Bbb Q_p$?

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Yeah, so in $\Bbb Q_2$ for instance, $f$ has solution $(1,1,0)$. Then, we have to check that the derivative is non-zero for Hensel to lift it right? So, in $\Bbb Q_2^3$ $f$ has solution $(x,y,z)=(1,1,0)$, so substituting $y=1$ and $z=0$ gives $g(x)=3x^2+11$ with derivative $g'(x)=6x$. Then, substituting $x=1$ gives $g'(1)=6\neq 0$. Is this right or is it actually $g'(1)\equiv 0\bmod 2$?

Comment: If you are seeking solutions in $\Bbb Q_2$ it may help to recall that all elements of $1+8\Bbb Z_2$ are squares there.